# Abrupt behaviour of KDB Real type

Tags: kdb

I am having an issue when comparing float and real. Here are some examples:

**KDB version:2.7 (2012-02-20)**

1. 4.7e = 4.7f
   output: false

   Reason: Kdb converts 4.7e to 4.6999998e

   so, 4.7e < 4.7f  ---> ouput:true
2. 4.347e = 4.347f

   output:false

   Reason: 4.347e gets converted to 4.3470001e

   so, 4.347e>4.347f  ---> output:true

I am not sure what is going on here. More examples you try,more varieties you'll get in answer.

Comment: Look at questions and answers here on SO on the topic of *floating-point* numbers and arithmetic.  If anyone tells you to read Goldberg's paper *What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic* ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also some specific info on the kdb wiki (not sure if you've already seen them)

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/precision/#float-precision

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/precision/#comparison-tolerance

Comment: Thanks. I went through  that and it helped in getting some info. So basically there is problem with floating values itself.

Comment: No, your conclusion that *there is problem with floating values itself* is wrong.  The problems come from uninformed expectations that computer arithmetic will match mathematical arithmetic.

Comment: I meant that only that operations involving floating values will have issues and will not be same as what we expect.